# Why does this use of std::transform cause exc_bad_access

Tags: c++, qt, stl, exc-bad-access

I have this code (roughly) in a cpp app:

```
QList<Foo> rawAssets = getlist();
QVector<std::pair<QString, QString>> assets;
std::transform(rawAssets.begin(), rawAssets.end(), assets.begin(), makePair);
```

That causes `exc_bad_access` to throw when I use `assets` again.

However, if I change `assets.begin()` to `std::back_inserter(assets)` then it works as I expect.

I found tutorials for `std::transform` showing both kinds of usage. Why is it wrong in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've just declared `QVector<std::pair<QString, QString>> assets`; it's *empty.* `assets.begin()` is therefore equal to `assets.end()`, and points past-the-end of the empty vector.

The third parameter of `std::transform` is an iterator through which `transform` will *write* the results of the transformation (and increment it after each write).

When you pass in `assets.begin()`, `transform` will write through this past-the-end iterator, resulting in an out-of-bounds write. It's roughly the same as doing `char x[3]; x[4] = 'a';`

When you pass in `std::back_inserter(assets)`, you create a special iterator such that writing through it actually *inserts* the written element into `assets`. So all is well.

The first form could be used if `assets` was already of sufficient size, and you wanted to *overwrite* the elements in it. The second form is used when you want to *extend* `assets` with the results of the transformation.

Comment: `assets.begin() is therefore equal to assets.end()` that's the piece I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`assets` starts out as an empty vector.

`transform()`'s third parameter is an output iterator. Your code is essentially equivalent to the following:

```
QVector<std::pair<QString, QString>> assets;

auto output_iter=assets.begin();

// You now call transform(), passing output_iter
//
// transform() then essentially does the following:

*output_iter++ = /* first transform()ed value */;
*output_iter++ = /* second transform()ed value */;

// ... and so on.
```

That's how `transform()` works. Since `assets()` is an empty vector, `begin()` gives you the ending iterator value, and then the code proceeds to merrily write past the end of the vector, and crap all over itself.

You have two basic options:

1. Before obtaining the `begin()` iterator, `resize()` the vector to the number of elements you're about to `transform()`, so `transform()` ends up filling out a pre-resized array's contents, exactly. However, since your data comes from a list, this is not easily available, so:
2. Pass a [std::back_insert_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) to `transform()`, instead of an iterator to the empty array.

Answer (score 0):

`std::transform()` assumes that it can write directly into the output.  Which in your case is a vector of zero size.  You can fix the bug by explicitly resizing your vector to the size of the transform input, or by using `back_inserter` as you already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

If you resize `assets` to the same size as `rawAssets` before the `transform`, it won't cause a bad access. Using a `back_insert_iterator` causes `push_back` to be called for each iterator of `transform`. Without that, it tries to access the first, second, third, etc element of `assets`, which is still empty, therefore causing a bad access.